# Proxy generated for WCF creating Message Contracts

Tags: wcf, proxy

I'm consuming a WCF service in my project for which I've added the reference using 'Add Service Reference...'. I expected it to generate a clean proxy with a ServiceClient entity and  the Interface. Instead, I see that it has created a MethodNameRequest, MethodNameRequestBody, MethodNameResponse, MethodNameResponseBody entities for each OperationContract method.

So while invoking the service methods, the proxy passes to the service method an instance of MethodNameRequest with the input parameters of the method as the properties of the RequestBody. See below an example of a call to AboutInformationGet() method which doesn't accept any parameters.

```
        public WCFDynamicInvocation.PostingService.AboutModel AboutInformationGet() {
        WCFDynamicInvocation.PostingService.AboutInformationGetRequest inValue = new WCFDynamicInvocation.PostingService.AboutInformationGetRequest();
        inValue.Body = new WCFDynamicInvocation.PostingService.AboutInformationGetRequestBody();
        WCFDynamicInvocation.PostingService.AboutInformationGetResponse retVal = ((WCFDynamicInvocation.PostingService.IMIGQPosting)(this)).AboutInformationGet(inValue);
        return retVal.Body.AboutInformationGetResult;
    }
```

I believe this behavior is what one would expect to see in a Webservice Proxy. Hence I suspect that the WCF service is not properly configured.

Did someone here face this issue? What would be the change to be done at the service so that the proxy generated is similar to the WCF service.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this for some time, I've finally found that the cause for the message contracts in the proxy was the service interface had the following attribute:

```
[XmlSerializerFormat(Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal, Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
```

As I understand, I could decorate the DataContracts with the following attribute to avoid wrapping
    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]

but the response still gets wrapped as the OperationContract hasn't been modified.

As there were no particular need to use XMLSerializer in place of WCF's default DataContractSerializer, we would remove the XmlSeralizerFormat decoration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b9655eeb-cdbb-4703-87d8-00deac340173).

Right click your service reference -> Configure service reference... -> Check if "Always generate message contracts" check box is checked. Uncheck it and hit OK to regenerate the proxy to see if you get a normal proxy.

Comment: Thanks Praburaj for the link. The 'Always generate message contracts' checkbox is unchecked. Also, I went through and made sure that all objects had DataContract attribute as was the case with the OP. The issue still persists but now I know I'm not the only one facing that issue. :)

Comment: @RonalR, Alternatively did you try generating the reference with svcutil? Do you see the same behavior?

Comment: as expected the Svcutil generates an identical proxy class.